# Can anyone identify this tiny insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Very high magnification, size of a very small ant. Found in Menorca, spain[image]

Comment: define "very small ant". One millimeter in length?

Comment: I would say 2mm/3mm but that's a guesstimate now as these have gone.

Comment: These are Barklice (order "Psocoptera"); the out-of-focus photo will probably forbid going deeper.

Answer (score 1):

That's a barklouse, order Psocoptera. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psocoptera
It's very hard to identify those to species in a picture.